# Drag-and-drop from my program to third-party program in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop, execute

I am trying to open multiple files using a third-party program, by calling it from VB.NET. By default, the program I am using, through command line, only opens one file at a time - and if I call it again, it opens a new instance. (when started in GUI, I can drop many files on it).

Now I open it with

```
Shell("program file")
```

If the program is running, I want to add "file" on top of the running instance instead of starting a new instance.

Something like:

```
If Not procExists then
    Shell("program file")
else
   'I want to drop "file" onto running "program" (or procNumber since I have it)
End If
```

I have been trying to find some example of drag and drop code for VB.NET or c# but I could not find things I could understand - I read about WM_DROPFILES and the fact that it may not work in Windows 7 (which is exactly where I need it to work). I also found a workaround for MFC, http://helgeklein.com/blog/2010/03/how-to-enable-drag-and-drop-for-an-elevated-mfc-application-on-vistawindows-7/ but my limited understanding of that example (other than the fact that I can't make it work, or use it for my vb.net application) is that it applies to dropping items on MY application, not on  a different one.

Something else that I found - and again, it seems meant to drop files in MY application, not a different one - and still opens a separate instance of that program, and I really don't want that - has something like:

```
Public Const WM_DROPFILES As Integer = 563
Private Declare Sub DragFinish Lib "Shell32.dll" (ByVal hdrop As IntPtr)
Private Declare Function DragAcceptFiles Lib "shell32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal accept As Boolean) As Long
Private Declare Function DragQueryFile Lib "shell32.dll" (ByVal hdrop As IntPtr, ByVal ifile As Integer, ByVal fname As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal fnsize As Integer) As Integer

Public Sub HandleDroppedFiles(ByVal file As String)
    If Len(file) > 0 Then
        'do something but what ? If I call the program, it will open a new instance
    End If
End Sub
```

Where can I get an example of WM_DROPFILES - or something else - that I can me to work ?

**Edit**: using suggested answer, I have tried:

```
For Each filename in filelist
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(program, filename)
Next
```

Unfortunately, just like `Shell("program filename")`, it opened lots of instances of "program", instead o loading all the files in the same instance.

Answer (score 2):

Windows doesn't do anything spectacular when you drop a file on a shortcut.  It simply starts the program and passes the path to the dropped file as a command line argument.  This can be customized, but it is not very common.

So just do what Windows does, much easier to get going than the nearly impossible task of simulating a D+D:

```
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("program file", file);
```

Be sure to pass the full path to the file (like c:\foo\bar.baz), incremental paths won't work.

Comment: I have tried the above option (please see question edit), but as far as I can see it does exactly what the Shell("program filename") did.